# In IntelliJ IDEA, how can I reset the per file indentation decision?

Tags: intellij-idea, indentation, setting

IntelliJ IDEA shows a small notice at the top of a file when the detected indentation inside the file does not match that configured in the settings dialog. It also allows to switch the indentation to the configured setting, which is a useful thing.

But now I have two files for which I would like to revert that decision and *not* apply my locally defined indentation. However this appears to be impossible...

Even changing the configured indentation setting does *not* have an effect on those files I once made that decision for. It appears that the decision is set and stored as a per file configuration.

Question: is there any way to *remove* that per file setting again?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Edit -> Convert Indents -> To Spaces / To Tabs ?
This should be file specific.

Comment: Certainly this is file specific, thanks. However this is an action, not a settings. Indentation is converted, but that setting is not changed. So the conversion is reverted upon the next touch of the file.